# $d(x,y)=(x-y)^2$ isn't a metric on $\mathbb R$

Tags: metric-spaces, real-numbers

$d$ isn't a metric on $\mathbb R$ because triangular inequality doesn't holds .As $d(x,z)=(x-z)^2=(x-y+y-z)^2$ . Could you please tell me how to proceed further?

Answer (score 5):

To show that the triangle inequality does not hold, all you have to do, is to show that for a nice tuple $(x,y,z)$ we have $(x-y)^2 > (x-z)^2 + (z-y)^2$.

So let see if we can find some nice tuple $(x,y,z)$.
$(1,2,3)$ gives $(1-2)^2 = 1< 5 = (1-3)^2 + (3-2)^2$.
$(2,3,1)$ gives $(2-3)^3 = 1 < 5= (2-1)^2 + (1-3)^2$.
$(3,1,2)$ gives $(3-1)^2 = 4 > 2 =(3-2)^2 + (2-1)^2$.

So we see that for $x=3$, $y=1$ and $z=2$ the triangle inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

$$(x-z)^2=(x-y+y-z)^2=(x-y)^2+ 2(x-y)(y-z) +(y-z)^2$$ which does not have to be less or equal $(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2$. For example take $x=3, y=2, z=0$.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're asking how to prove that the triangular inequality doesn't hold. If that's the case, you have to find $x,y,z,\in\mathbb R$ such as $d(x,z)>d(x,y)+d(y,z)$.

As you wrote:$$d(x,z)=((x-y)+(y-z))^2=(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+2(x-y)(y-z)$$$$=d(x,y)+d(y,z)+2(x-y)(y-z)$$ so you should find $x,y,z\in\mathbb R$ such as $(x-y)(y-z)>0$ which is easy.

Comment: As, a2+b2<a2+b2+2ab ,so we can say that (x−y)2+(y−z)2<(x−y)2+(y−z)2+2(x−y)(y−z) this implies that d(x,z)>d(x,y)+d(y,z). Am I right ?

Comment: Yes you're right **if** $(x-y)(y-z)>0$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Expand $d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ $\text{    }$